# Spinning CarouselPanel in ComboBox via Mouse

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am currently re-templating the `ComboBox` in a Metro XAML application.

The `ItemsPanel` is the standard `CarouselPanel`, which acts like a tumbler, endlessly revolving through the items list - nice !

An added nice detail, is that in the VS/Blend simulator if you 'flick' the items with the touch pointer then the carousel 'spins', rather like the Date tumbler in Windows Phone.

My problem is, when used in Desktop mode (via a mouse) I cant re-created the same spinning effect. there seems to be some kind of failure in the maouse/touch guesture translation.

Doesn anyone have any ideas about how to get this to work ?

Comment: Any news on this ? Having same issue. Do you have an example?

Comment: Could you confirm the `ComboBox` has focus when you are testing?

Comment: It's considered polite to mark the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought it might be like the `GridView` which does not bubble up the mouse wheel events. But then I tried the code below and the mouse wheel does spin it. It doesn't do this in Blend, but it does it at runtime fine.

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <x:String>0</x:String>
        <x:String>1</x:String>
        <x:String>2</x:String>
        <x:String>3</x:String>
        <x:String>4</x:String>
        <x:String>5</x:String>
        <x:String>6</x:String>
        <x:String>7</x:String>
        <x:String>8</x:String>
        <x:String>9</x:String>
        <x:String>10</x:String>
        <x:String>11</x:String>
        <x:String>12</x:String>
        <x:String>13</x:String>
        <x:String>14</x:String>
        <x:String>15</x:String>
        <x:String>16</x:String>
        <x:String>17</x:String>
        <x:String>18</x:String>
        <x:String>19</x:String>
        <x:String>20</x:String>
        <x:String>21</x:String>
        <x:String>22</x:String>
        <x:String>23</x:String>
        <x:String>24</x:String>
        <x:String>25</x:String>
        <x:String>26</x:String>
        <x:String>27</x:String>
        <x:String>28</x:String>
        <x:String>29</x:String>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Does this actually work on 8.1 with a mouse only?  I cannot get a CarouselPanel to show that behaviour if I roll a mouse over my control, or click the dropdown on the combo and roll the mouse.

Has this behaviour disappeared?